# How to create a jar file which won't have dependency version conflicts with others link it n

Tags: maven, jar, java

I want to create a jar for a java library (lets call this mylibrary). mylibary has many dependencies, built with maven. For example say mylibrary depends on a jar called foo, and mylibrary uses version 1.1 of foo.

I want to give this java library out to other people. They will link in my library and use the APIs it provides.

When a user builds their project (lets call it theirlibrary), suppose they want to use version 1.2 of foo. So their project contains two dependencies:
mylibrary 1.0
foo 1.2
This causes a jar version conflict because mylibrary is using foo 1.1 and theirlibrary is using foo 1.2 and generally does not work.

Is it possible to use a special build target in maven to resolve this issue? That is, everything in mylibrary will be bundled into one jar, and only be able to load other classes within the mylibrary jar.

And the classes the theirlibrary loads in from the mylibrary jar only include the APIs mylibrary intends to expose, and not its dependencies. If the user wants to use foo 1.2, then they are free to do that.

Basically I dont want mylibrary 1.0 to force foo 1.1 onto theirlibrary. theirlibrary should be free to use foo 1.2 if it wants to do that.

I've looked into ClassLoaders as a solution, but I don't think this will work. It seems like class loaders only allow the instantiator of the class to have control. I.e. theirlibrary could use ClassLoaders to fix this issue, but I don't think there is a lot I can do from mylibrary. I don't want to force theirlibrary to use ClassLoaders in their code.

Is this possible in java? Or is this a shortcoming of java?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you should use the `provided` scope in your dependency. This means that the library/application that will use your lib should provide the version of `foo`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <!-- this version is applicable only in your project -->
  <version>1.1</version> 
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that this means that all projcts that uses your library should declare the foo dependency.

More about dependencies scopes can be found [at the docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Comment: Does this prevents you from choosing the version of foo in mylibrary's implementation. I don't think this solution works quite as I hopped.

mylibrary will end up using version 1.2 instead of 1.1 if theirlibrary changes it. Correct?

Thanks for the help btw

Comment: The version you choose to test against it is declared inside the mylibrary's pom. You may try to automate some test again multiple versions. But I think I don't understand your question, because you want the user to choose the foo version and now you're asking me to prevent the foo version (I'm confused).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven shade plugin (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) using its class relocation feature.

That way, all classes of "foo" would be relocated to a different package (in this case myprivate.org.foo), creating, in fact, a new private instance of foo used exclusively by your library:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>org.foo</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>myprivate.org.foo</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Note however that this technique leads to massivly blown up jars. Normally foo 1.2 and 1.1 should be compatible enough that your library should work with 1.2 so. So still, theirlibrary is free to use 1.2. The shade plugin's relocation is target at situations, where there are incompatibilities between versions (asm 1.x and 2.x for example).

So please consider if shadings is really necessary.

An alternative using different classloaders would be using OSGI which allows the same library being present in different version.